# Metric Space with No Local Isometries?

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

We know there are metric spaces with no non-trivial (global) isometries. For example, consider the Euclidean plane $(\mathbb{R}^2, d)$. Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the set $\{(0,0), (1,0),(0,2)\}$. Now consider the metric space $(X, d_X)$ where $d_X$ is the metric induced from $d$. One can easily verify that the only isometry $f: X \rightarrow X$ is the identity map.

My question is whether there are also metric spaces with no non-trivial "local isometries" of a certain kind. Here's what I mean by that...

*Definition*. We say a metric space $(X,d)$ has has a (non-trivial) *local isometry* if there are distinct points $p,q \in X$ with respective neighborhoods $O_p$ and $O_q$ (in the induced topology) and an isometry $f: O_p \rightarrow O_q$ such that $f(p)=q$.

There are cheap examples of metric spaces with no non-trivial local isometries. Just consider any metric space $(X,d)$ where $X$ contains only one element. My question is the following...

*Question*. Is there a a metric space with at least two elements which fails to have a non-trivial local isometry?

Comment: Can $O_p$ and $O_q$ not be open, or must they be open neighbourhoods?

Comment: A generic Riemannian metric on any compact manifold of dimension $\geq 2$ will have this property ("nowhere locally homogeneous").  See e.g. Sunada's [celebrated 1985 paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/1971195) on isospectral manifolds.

Comment: Sure, they can fail to be open as I set things up here...

Comment: Thanks for the reference @user10354138! Is there an explicit example to consider to help me better understand?

Comment: Not related to the Riemannian metric example, which may be easier to visualize:  Tweak the usual Cantor set construction to remove noncentral chunk and make sure at each stage none of the residual segments have equal length (including previous stages), the final Cantor-like set will have no local isometry.

Comment: Nice idea! I will think about how to fill in the details...